Customer asks, if the PostgreSQL database can be encrypted
I have a customer that requests the database to be encrypted, in case it get's stolen. Beside that being absolute bullcrap in my eyes, and encrypting the files on disk would be useless because the key is obviously also in the disk, is there something I am missing? Is this actually done? Or is that a Windows thing, where Windows has maybe a crypt store that is not accessible be the user but somehow does the decryption magic? I am working on Linux. Or do these managers just speak of the backup files in that case?
Thanks a lot in advance.

"the key is obviously also in the disk" -- this is not at all obvious though. Have you seen this?

always ask "what is the problem you are trying to solve?" encrypting data at different points addresses different types of potential compromise. for data at rest (in a file) file system or disk encryption protects against physical theft of the device; file encryption protects against theft of the files (as in downloading); encrypting data in the application (so the encrypted data is stored in the DB) protects against accidental exposure of data to admins or others with DB access. network encryption protects data in motion. None of them are bullcrap. All Which risk are you trying to mitigate?

@mustaccio: Look like I have a lot to learn here still... :)

You can encrypt the data files, and you can encrypt the data that you store in the database.

Encrypting the data files protects your from people who steal your hard disk, find your old hard disks in the junk (if your forgot to shredder them) or gain access to your file system backups. It leaves you vulnerable to people who have access via the client, because to the client the data appear unencrypted.
There is no built-in solution for encrypted data files in open source PostgreSQL. You can either encrypt on the file system level (which is not great, because the files appear in clear text to anybody who gets shell access to the database machine), or you can use a modified PostgreSQL server with support for "transparent data encryption". A disclaimer is in place: I work for a company that offers such software.
Encrypting the data files does not necessarily mean that the key is on disk. It could mean that somebody has to enter a secret when the system starts, or that a HSM is in use.

Encrypting the data that get stored in the database offers better protection. You can either use functions from the pgcrypto extension for that or encrypt the data in the application. The latter is much better, because that way, the database never sees the clear text data or the encryption key.  Moreover, you can choose to encrypt only those parts of the data that need protection.
The downside of this level of security is that, perhaps apart from equality search, you cannot use index support for the encrypted data.

It can, multiple ways. Encrypting the backup isn't even mentioned because that's obvious. The thing with a running database being entirely encrypted along with the rest of the file system in case it gets stolen did get a mention:

Data Partition Encryption
Storage encryption can be performed at the file system level or the block level. Linux file system encryption options include eCryptfs and EncFS, while FreeBSD uses PEFS. Block level or full disk encryption options include dm-crypt + LUKS on Linux and GEOM modules geli and gbde on FreeBSD. Many other operating systems support this functionality, including Windows.
This mechanism prevents unencrypted data from being read from the drives if the drives or the entire computer is stolen.

